# How to save Enums as strings in Elasticsearch 5.6 without Attribute mappings (using NEST)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to store all my enums in form of strings in my Elasticsearch index. Since the Model I am using needs to be independent from any specific technology, I can't use [attribute mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/attribute-mapping.html#attribute-mapping).

I know that you can pass a `SerializerFactory` when creating the `ConnectionSettings`, but I do not know what option will change the serialization of enums.

Here is the code I use to connect with NEST:

```
var serializers = new SerializerFactory(<what to put here?>);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(myUri, serializers)
    .DefaultIndex(myIndex)
    .InferMappingFor<MyModel>(m => m
        .IdProperty(s => s.MyId)
    );
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Can I use the `SerializerFactory` to save all enums as strings? Is there any other option without using the attribute mappings?

---

Elasticsearch version:

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.0",
    "build_hash" : "781a835",
    "build_date" : "2017-09-07T03:09:58.087Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
}
```

NEST Version: `5.5.0` (most recent nuget)

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/serialization.html. Deriving from `JsonNetSerializer`, you can add a `StringEnumConverter` for any type that is an `enum`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Nest/CommonAbstractions/SerializationBehavior/JsonNetSerializer.cs#L42

Comment: This is using an old version of the client, but the `Func<Type, JsonConverter>` delegate is probably what you want to add to `ContractConverters` on your derived serializer: http://markswanderingthoughts.nl/post/82479251894/configuring-custom-jsonconverters-in-nest-for-elasticsea

Comment: @RussCam Thanks, your first comment helped a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @RussCam I could find the solution. Here is the code I am using now:

```
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(myUri));
var connection = new HttpConnection();
var serializers = new SerializerFactory((s, v) => s.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()) );

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, connection, serializers)
    .DefaultIndex(StatusIndex)
    .InferMappingFor<MyModel>(m => m
        .IdProperty(s => s.MyId)
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Line 3 is the important one. The `StringEnumConverter` that is added to the `Converters` of the `SerializerFactory` will make every enum be serialized to a string and deserialized from a string (using this `ElasticClient`).

Answer (score 4):

I used a similar approach to @Leifb is suggesting (using StringEnumConverter on the property):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] 
public MyEnum Status {get;set;}
```

However, this gives an issue if you use automapping for the types, so I created a generic Enum to String property visitor for that:

```
var result = await _client.PutIndexTemplateAsync(
    p.TemplateName, s=>s
        .Template(p.Template)
        .Mappings(m=>m
            .Map(p.TemplateName, mm=>mm
                .AutoMap<MyType>(new EnumAsStringPropertyVisitor())
            )
        ));


public class EnumAsStringPropertyVisitor : NoopPropertyVisitor
{
    public override void Visit(
        INumberProperty type,
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo,
        ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase attribute) 
    {
        if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        { 
            type.Type = "keyword"; 
        }
    }
}
```